# Mouse Click Problem

Tags: 11.04, mouse

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on Compaq Presario c772tu. I just noticed that I am unable to click on links/buttons/text if the mouse is in particular areas on the screen. The same link/button/text are clickable if I scroll a bit up or down.

Basically it feels like there is an invisible grid on the screen where the mouse is unable to identify items to click on. The same happens on desktop icons too.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/755459) (it's an invisible window that's always on top, preventing any clicks to reach what you are pointing at).

To temporarily fix it, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `unity`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will restart just Unity, without closing any of your open applications).